# Azure DevOps Query: How to get all WorkItems that have been set to state "done" after a specific date?

Tags: azure-devops

We use Azure DevOps queries as a helping hand in creating release notes.

Up until the last release we used the following query configuration to determine all finished workitems and bugs since the last release:

[image]

This worked fine until, for some reason, a lot of "old" workitems got their backlog priority changed and therefore have an updated "Changed Date" value. So now we have a lot of already released work items in our query result. Using the "Changed Date" was obviously not a good idea. We need an other property with deciding capabilities.

When I took a look at the history of a work item I discovered that the state graph shows the information we need. 
[image]

I tried to replace the "Changed Date" Parameter in the query with "Closed Date", "Finish Date" and "State Change Date". Unfortunately all of them don't have values and therefore cannot be used.

How do I get the date of the state change of a work item from "committed" to "done"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has introduced a new filter in the queries for Azure DevOps called "State Change Date". You can use this parameter and check which work Items have been modified after a particular date.

[image: VSTS - Azure DevOps Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I made a typing error in my question and updated it. I tried using "State Change Date" but non of my work items have any values in this property.

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the correct direction. "State Change Date" is the answer but there seems to be a bug with it when used in a custom WIT, which we have! I'll mark this as the correct answer since the problem is located otherwise.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/373206/state-changed-date-not-available-on-our-custom-wit.html